# url did not send correct data ,what can i do for send the correct values

Tags: php

i want to send data with url 
and my code php is:

```
<?php    
$db_host="127.0.0.1"; $db_uid="root"; $db_pass="";     
$db_name="highway_db";    $db_con =    
mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass,$db_name);
$longitude =(isset( $_GET['lon`enter code here`gitude']));
$latitude = (isset($_GET['latitude']));
$timestamp = (isset($_GET['timestamp']));
$result = mysqli_query($db_con,"INSERT INTO accident (longitude, latitude,   timestamp) 
VALUES ($longitude, $latitude, $timestamp)");
if($result == true)
echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
else
echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
mysqli_close($db_con);
?>
```

and my table is accident have id,longitude,latitude and timestamp 
id is AUTO_INCREMENT.
but thme problem when i use this url :

```
http://127.0.0.1/addAccidents.php?longitude=3.54&latitude=3.09&timestamp=2016-04-25 11:11:00 
i find that is add to my table accident 
longitude=1
latitude =1,
timestamp =0000-00-00 00:00:00.
```

and this my problem with url please help me

Comment: what is the data type in table?

Comment: tell us your table columns datatype.

Comment: probably shouldn;t have that space in the timestamp in the url either

Comment: You need to change the field types in the db to match the input content, float, datetime, etc...

Comment: Divyesh Savaliya type of the data: longitude and latitude ara double but timestamp  is datetime

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 $result = mysqli_query($db_con,"INSERT INTO accident (longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('".$longitude."', '".$latitude."', '".$timestamp."')");
```

Echo the sql query and try to run query directly in your phpmyadmin and also check your database table column type.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the setting of hte variables around - you should anyway because even if the GET value is not present - this code will still try to insert values into the db, such as :

```
if(isset( $_GET['longitude'])){$longitude =$_GET['longitude']};
```

and then write code that only allows the writing to the db if the three values are set.

Comment: thank you very much
But unfortunately this does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
isset() is a function which checks if a given variable has contents or not. If it has it returns 1 and if not it return 0.  

In all 3 below statements, you are just checking the variables, you have not assigned  values to your variables!

Try to use this code here, it should work if GET REQUEST with those specified parameters is sent!

<?php    
$db_host="127.0.0.1"; 
$db_uid="root"; 
$db_pass="";     
$db_name="highway_db";    
$db_con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass,$db_name);


$longitude = isset($_GET['longitude'])?$_GET['longitude']:"";
$latitude = isset($_GET['latitude'])?$_GET['latitude']:"";
$timestamp = isset($_GET['timestamp'])?$_GET['timestamp']:"";

$query = "INSERT INTO accident (longitude,latitude,timestamp) VALUES ($longitude,$latitude,$timestamp)";

if(mysqli_query($db_con,$query)){
echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}
else{
echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
echo "ERROR= ". mysql_error();
}
mysqli_close($db_con);
?>
Let me know how it goes....
```

Comment: i looked at that too and thought that isset returns true or false rather than 1 or 0, but obviously I was mistaken

Comment: "entre code here" is from the original post, I just copied it!!... It should carry the name of of the variable to be inserted i.e "longitude" @MoulayAhmedBekkaoui

Comment: Checkout my post edits, then let me know how it goes... @MoulayAhmedBekkaoui

Comment: it return "{"query_result":"FAILURE"}ERROR=" @Michael Kimollo

Comment: add this line in quotes   "echo ($query);"     just  before if(mysqli_query($db_con,$query)) statement; then post the result here @MoulayAhmedBekkaoui

Comment: the result is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)@Michael Kimollo